# Mysql Query never stops

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with 3 columns

```
PageDescription(varchar(50)) | ParentID (int) | CategoryID (int)
```

Here is the table data

```
Fruit||1
Apples|1|2
```

here is the query i'm running

```
SELECT PageDescription,(SELECT PageDescription
      FROM tblpages a
     WHERE a.ParentID = tblpages.CategoryID)
      AS 'Page Parent'
 FROM tblpages
```

This query does not stop processing, is there a better way to handle this query?

Comment: what are you trying to do??? what suppose to be the result expected?

Comment: what does the query execution plan say?

Comment: I'm just running it as a select nothing unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a join.

```
SELECT a.PageDescription, b.PageDescription as Parent
FROM tblpages a
LEFT JOIN tblpages b ON a.CategoryID = b.ParentID
```

Comment: Xdazz thats the thing i dont want to join the whole query because that will exclude where ParentID is null, and I want to have those rows

Comment: use left outer join then, that'll include everything from the first table, and include anything it can find from the second table

Comment: inner join will not work here, what will happen if a page doesnt have any parent page

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JOIN` to perform this:

```
SELECT t1.PageDescription
  , t2.PageDescription as PageParent
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2
  on t1.ParentId = t2.CategoryId
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c613/10)

Using a `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to include the items that have a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to name yout two tables:

```
SELECT b.PageDescription,(SELECT PageDescription
      FROM tblpages a
     WHERE a.ParentID = b.CategoryID)
      AS 'Page Parent'
 FROM tblpages b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PageDescription,p1.PageDescription
      FROM tblpages p1
      LEFT JOIN p2 on p1.parentId=p2.categoryID
     WHERE 1;
```